# Detecting GUI window close in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to detect when a GUI window has been closed ? I am building an editor tool and I need to perform some actions after the window has been closed. Ideally, if there is a callback or event that notifies me then that would be perfect. I searched a lot but I didn't find anything. It might be possible that I'm searching using a wrong keyword also. Are there any work arounds ? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Full source code and original post can be found [here](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/unity-detect-gui-window-createdclosed-event/):

You can try using a boolean property to fake the window close/open effect, whenever the **setter** is called, some function **OnWindowClosed()** is get called:

Tested on Mac OSX:
[image]

```
bool _bWindowActive;
public bool bWindowActive {
    get { return _bWindowActive;}
    set { 
        _bWindowActive = value;
        if (!bWindowActive) {
            //This is called everytime, when bWindowActive = false;
            OnWindowClosed ();  
        }
    }
}

public void OnWindowClosed ()
{
    Debug.Log ("Windows Closed");
}

public void OnGUI() {

    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 20, 100, 20), "Show Window"))
        bWindowActive = true;
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10,60,100,20), "Close Window"))
        bWindowActive = false;

    if (bWindowActive) {
        GUI.Window (0, new Rect(200, 10, 200, 200), DoMyWindow, "My Window");
    }
}

public void DoMyWindow(int windowID) {
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10,20,100,20), "Hello World"))
        print ("Got a click");
}
```

Comment: Hi, the solution looks great. But in this case, you have created a custom button. But any idea how I could link this to the traditional (x) button that appears at the top right corner of an editor window. I am developing this tool for artists. So I want to keep it as simple as possible. Else I will have to just create a custom button and use that for closing.

Comment: I actually found a EditorWindow.OnDestory() which I wasn't able to during the whole of yesterday. But I really liked your solution - an interesting way of doing it. Thanks!